# Tkinter navigate page to page with the same background

Tags: python, oop, button, background, tkinter

I don't know How structure the GUI of my program...

I don't have big experience with GUI programming, i know all the widgets, the 
geometry managers, the "object-oriented" method in Tkinter, but i don't understand 
how combine all this things...

I want to create a program with an image in background where there is a button and if i press this button i switch in another page and the button disappears

Like this : https://moqups.com/iampirla@gmail.com/wyM7CyET/p:a80e8d902

How i can structure my code to do this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: edited... does it have any sense now?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you want your main window to open another one you should try using the Toplevel class (check for example this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_toplevel.htm)

Comment: Does the following answer help? It doesn't address the background image, but it addresses switching between "pages" http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/7432

Comment: thank you bryan!!! only one question... In the code which you have sent, in  the line : " for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)"                                                                            why in "frame=F(container,self)" container is the first argument and self the second?

Comment: @iampirla: because `container` is the parent widget (Frame) into which the new page should go. `controller` is a reference to an object that can be used from any page to open any other page.

Comment: yes i've seen... you are a genius!!!

Comment: why you name self with controller?

Answer (score 0):

You could use *pack_forget()* this removes the widget although allows you to use it later if you wish. You could do the first page and then use some code like below. To clear the page. This could then reference the next thing you wish to do using in this example question().

```
def answred():
    nameLabel.pack_forget()
    nameEntry.pack_forget()
    nameButton.pack_forget()
    classQuestion.pack_forget()
    button1.pack_forget()
    button2.pack_forget()
    button3.pack_forget()
    question()
```

You could this but not remove the background widgets